# Eclipse Field Access Declaring Type

Tags: eclipse

I was messing around with the getter/setter settings for Eclipse and I came across the "Field access in declaring type:". It leads to two choices of "use setter and getter" or "keep field reference". I tried both of them but I couldn't seem to find a difference between them. Could anyone notify me the difference between these two options?

[image: Example]

Comment: could you post a screenshot? i did not find it.

Comment: Yep, I added the link to the main post.

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: the icon looks like luna

Answer (score 1):

With the "use setter and getter"-option every access to the field will be replaced with the getter and the setter. 
eg:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.number + " " + this.text;
}
```

results in

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNumber() + " " + getText();
}
```

With the "keep field reference"-option the fields are not replaces, so your methods keep their (direct) call to the fields. so the internal methods do not change.

Often the first option is not necessary, since you set your field's visibility to private and create a getter, so other classes can get their value by the method, but not access directly.

Comment: Thanks! This will be extremely useful in future cases when I will need to keep the methods consistent.